# Images in a WPF Custom Control Library

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I need to put an image in the default view of a custom control.  However, whenever I try to test the control it can't locate the image.  I have tried to compile it as an embedded resource and just a plain resource in VS.  Neither of these have worked.  So is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: Thanks for all of your help.  I was able to use the Pack URI scheme to get to properly reference the image I needed to add.

Answer (score 4):

That's probably because you specified the image path as a relative path. You should use the [Pack URI Scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) to specify that the resource is in the current assembly. For instance :

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/MyImage.png"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an open-source library that allows you to include country flags in your WPF application via a value converter.  The flags images are stored as resources within the assembly.

[image]

It's available on NuGet:

> Install-Package FamFamFam.Flags.Wpf

The source is up on GitHub:

https://github.com/drewnoakes/famfamfam-flags-wpf

You can take a look to see how the images are embedded and the Pack URI scheme is used.