# WPF custom control library image resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Following answers from : [Images in a WPF Custom Control Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963538/images-in-a-wpf-custom-control-library) and [How can I get a BitmapImage from a Resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857732/how-can-i-get-a-bitmapimage-from-a-resource)

I made a simple custom control library:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControlLibrary1">
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid>

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="imageone.png" />
                        <Image Source="imageone.png" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Content="/imageone.png" />
                                <Image Source="/imageone.png" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="Resources/imageone.png" />
                        <Image Source="Resources/imageone.png" />
                             </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Content="/Resources/imageone.png" />
                                <Image Source="/Resources/imageone.png" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Content="../Resources/imageone.png" />
                                <Image Source="../Resources/imageone.png" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Content="..Resources/imageone.png" />
                                <Image Source="..Resources/imageone.png" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Content="..//Resources//imageone.png" />
                                <Image Source="..//Resources//imageone.png" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Content="pack://application:,,,/imageone.png" />
                                <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/imageone.png" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Content="pack://application:,,,/Resources/imageone.png"/>
                                <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/imageone.png"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Content="pack://application:,,,/WpfCustomControlLibrary1;v1.0.0.0;Resources/imageone.png"/>
                                <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfCustomControlLibrary1;v1.0.0.0;Resources/imageone.png"/>
                            </StackPanel>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>    
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And added imageone.png as a resource:

[image]

With build action set to resource.

I have tried adding the file to the themes folder holding the generic.xaml file. And changed the paths accordingly, but it still produces this output:

[image]

with no images.

Whats the correct way to reference an image in a custom control library?

I have also tried to reference the images in an application:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControlLibrary1;assembly=WpfCustomControlLibrary1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="500">
<Grid>
    <!--<custom:CustomControl1></custom:CustomControl1>-->
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Resources/imageone.png" />
            <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="Resources/imageone.png" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="/Resources/imageone.png" />
            <Image  Width="20" Height="20" Source="/Resources/imageone.png" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="pack://application:,,,/Resources/imageone.png"/>
            <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/imageone.png"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

in designer view I can see a preview of the images which tells me the paths are correct. 
However the output still doesn't produce the images.

I am guessing it is some sort of build order problem?
All help appreciated.

**EDIT**

Switching the image to an *Embedded Resource* works for the window but not the control.

**Edit2**

Switching to an embedded resources works for the control library however, the image also needs to be in the solution that runs the control. Is there a way where the image will just be from the DLL and no need for the user to reference it?

Comment: Try setting the _Build Action_ for your `imageone.png` file to either _Content_ or _Embedded Resource_ and rerunning your application.

Comment: @Ash, OP says: _With build action set to resource_

Comment: Swapping to _embeded resource_ instead of _resource_ has worked for the images shown in the window but not the control

Comment: If the image you're trying to reference is in another assembly, then you have to include that assembly's name in the pack URI.

Comment: Switching to _content_ has worked for the control. Much appreciated

Comment: You should not add images as project resources. Instead, just directly add an image file (e.g. a PNG) to your project structure, e.g. to an `Images` project folder. Then set its Build Action to `Resource` (nothing else!), and load it by a [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx). See e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25714375/1136211

Comment: @Clemens Might not have been clear by my wording: _"I have tried adding the file to the themes folder"_

Comment: Then the Image's Source should be `pack://application:,,,/Themes/imageone.png` (or short in XAML, `Themes/imageone.png`). A full Pack URI including assembly name would be `pack://application:,,,/WpfCustomControlLibrary1;component/Themes/imageone.png` (if `WpfCustomControlLibrary1` actually is the assembly name)

Comment: Yes and that was already tried, will update the post to include that

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the Build Action for your `imageone.png` file to either *Content* or *Embedded Resource* and rerunning your application.

Comment: Explained the problem with your answer in original post

Comment: Back to square one really